# Make exception of particular rows

Tags: jquery

I'm using this jQuery code to cause table rows to highlight when I hover over them:

```
$('#link-table tr').hover(function ()
{
 $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
});
```

Is there anything I can alter on certain table rows to **prevent** them from highlighting when I hover over them?

Comment: you can add a condition if met then dont highlight if dont met highlight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add an `if`-condition in your hover handler to prevent this behavior.
For example, this code will only hightlight rows not having text `Header`:

```
$('#link-table tr').hover(function ()
{
    if (this.innerText !== 'Header')
        $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
});
```

However, JavaScript for intercepting hover is not justified for simple cases, when it is possible to do this using CSS.
You can simply use CSS `:hover` pseudo-class. If you want to enable this feature only for specified rows, then you can create your custom class:

```css
tr.hoverable:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="hoverable"><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr class="hoverable"><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr class="hoverable"><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4 (not hoverable)</td></tr>
  <tr class="hoverable"><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr class="hoverable"><td>6</td></tr>
</table>
```

The opposite option is to create a class which will disable the feature, while it will be enabled by default - it is up to you:

```css
tr:not(.not-hoverable):hover {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr class="not-hoverable"><td>4 (not hoverable)</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can I do something like `if (this.class !== "not-hoverable")`...? (But this.class doesn't seem to work so what is the correct syntax?)

Comment: @AndyGroom The correct syntax using jQuery is `if (!$(this).hasClass('not-hoverable')) { }` :)